# How to find the consumer topic and the group id from the __consumer_offsets topic in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to parse the logs from the `__consumer_offsets` topic in kafka. The idea is to find the group id, topic and the consumer which is creating load in my kafka cluster.

The command I am executing is below

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic __consumer_offsets --bootstrap-server brokers --formatter "kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager\$OffsetsMessageFormatter" --new-consumer --consumer.config consumer.conf
```

Now the output looks like this

```
[dedupeconsumergroup,daas.dedupe.avrosyslog.incoming,4]::[OffsetMetadata[8646,NO_METADATA],CommitTime 1538115746766,ExpirationTime 1538202146766]
[dedupeconsumergroup,daas.dedupe.avrosyslog.incoming,6]::[OffsetMetadata[8639,NO_METADATA],CommitTime 1538115746766,ExpirationTime 1538202146766]
```

Can someone help me in understanding this log or point me to the documentation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[dedupeconsumergroup,daas.dedupe.avrosyslog.incoming,6]::[OffsetMetadata[8639,NO_METADATA],CommitTime 1538115746766,ExpirationTime 1538202146766]
```

it means that consumer group with name *dedupeconsumergroup* read/commited offset *8639* on partition *6* in topic *daas.dedupe.avrosyslog.incoming*

which particular consumer read particular offset is probably little more complicated to find as you would have to know which partition was assigned to which consumer at a given point in time - it can change over time due to rebalancing.